# Integration by parts on a Kähler manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I am trying to make sense of integration by parts on a Kähler manifold $X$ equipped with a Kähler metric $\omega$. Given two smooth real functions $f$ and $h$ on $X$, I want to write down the integration by parts formula for the following:
$$\int_{X} h \Delta_{\omega} f \omega^n.$$
In local coordinates $\Delta_{\omega} f = \sum_{i, j} g^{i \bar\jmath} \partial_{\bar\jmath} \partial_{i}f$. My guess is that
$$\int_{X} h \Delta_{\omega} f \omega^n = -\int_{X} g^{i \bar\jmath} \partial_{\bar\jmath} h \partial_{i} f \omega^n.$$
However, this is not quite right since the LHS is real while the right hand side is not necessarily so. What is the correct formula? Is there a general strategy for thinking of such things in the complex case?

Comment: Try to write in terms of the exterior derivative and the Hodge star, since integration by parts is Stokes' theorem applied to an exact form.

Comment: The formula that you wrote is correct, and the RHS is real! The integrand is not always real-valued, but the integral is.

Comment: Is it obvious that the integral has to be real?@YangMills

Comment: It follows from the equation that you wrote, since the LHS is real. Proving your formula is a simple exercise using the divergence theorem (and the definition of covariant derivatives for a Kahler metric).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume $(X, d = \partial + \bar{\partial})$ to be a compact Kähler manifold.  The Kähler metric $g$ induces a metric on all differential forms, which we will also call $g$.  It follows that $\omega^n$ defines a Hilbert space of $i$-forms on $X$ by
$$
\langle u, v\rangle = \int_X g(u,v) \omega^n.
$$
For functions $u, v$, this is
$$
\langle u, v\rangle = \int_X u \bar{v} \omega^n.
$$

The adjoints $d^*$ and $\bar{\partial}^*$ are the operators such that for all $(i-1)$-form $u$ and all $i$-form $v$,
$$
\langle du,v\rangle = \langle u,d^*v\rangle,\quad\langle\bar{\partial}u,v\rangle = \langle u, \bar{\partial}^* v\rangle.
$$
The expression $\bar{\partial}^*$ equals $-* \bar{\partial} *$, where $*$ is the Hodge-$*$ and it involves the Kähler metric $g$.

The Laplacian is then
$$
\Delta_d = d^* d + d d^* = 2 (\bar{\partial} \bar{\partial}^* +\bar{\partial}^* \bar{\partial}) = 2 \Delta_{\bar{\partial}}.
$$
Since $h,f$ are functions,
we have
$$
\langle h, \Delta_{\bar{\partial}} f\rangle = \langle h,  (\bar{\partial} \bar{\partial}^* +\bar{\partial}^* \bar{\partial}) f\rangle = \langle\bar{\partial}^* h, \bar{\partial}^* f\rangle + \langle\bar{\partial} h, \bar{\partial} f\rangle = \langle\bar{\partial} h, \bar{\partial} f\rangle.
$$
In terms of your notation, this means
$$
\int_X h \Delta_\omega f \omega^n = \int_X g(\bar{\partial} h, \bar{\partial} f) \omega^n.
$$